# Comando para o Efeito de Preenchimento no VBA do Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Amigos, estou usando a dica, descrita no script do "Guru do Excel" em Criando Mapas Interativos no Excel:

```
Sub ColorirMapa()

Dim Microareas As Range 
Dim Celula As String 

For Each Microareas In Range (“Microareas”)
Celula = Cells (Microareas.Row, 4)
ActiveSheet.Shapes(Microareas).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Range(Celula).Interior.Color
Next Regiao

End Sub
```

Qual seria o comando no VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) para colocar textura pontilhada, listrada ou outras tipo efeito de preenchimento - no lugar de cores?

Answer (score 4):

Você precisaria inserir as seguintes propriedades de `Interior` do seu objeto `Cell` para ter o efeito desejado:

```
Range(Celula).Select

With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlVertical
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5296274
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Resultaria em algo parecido com isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Dica de ouro**

Muitas vezes queremos transformar em código VBA formatações, listas, congelar colunas mas não temos ideia por onde começar. O Excel tem um recurso que permite gravar as ações que você executa e transforma em códigos VBA para você.

Apesar do código gerado não ser o ideal, ele atende grande parte dos casos e além disso te dá uma ideia de como fazer o que você deseja.

1. Habilite a guia "Desenvolvedor" do seu Excel, em Arquivo > Opções > Personalizar faixa de opções.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Selecione a opção Gravar macro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. Faça o que você quiser no Excel. Terminado o que você precisava fazer, pare a execução da macro e analise o código gerado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]